# Bootstrap Fill Panel To Bottom of Row

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

Need help filling a Bootstrap panel to the bottom of the row.

Basically I have a 2 rows within a row, one half of the row is longer than the other. How can I make the second half of the row match the other.

Here is a screenshot of what I have.

[Page Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElYB.png)

and this is the code for how I am organizing it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default card-view" id="tour-dropdown">
            <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-left">
                        <p>Choose an account</p>
                        <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Details" method="get">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" asp-for="@Model.SelectedAccountValue" data-width="fit" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.AccountList)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.AccountValue">@item.AccountName (@item.AccountCode)</option>
                            }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default card-view pa-0">
                    <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body pa-0">
                            <div class="sm-data-box">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center pl-0 pr-0 data-wrap-left" id="tour-account-value">
                                            <span class="txt-dark block counter">@Model.AccountValue</span>
                                            <span class="weight-500 uppercase-font block">Account Value</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default card-view pa-0">
                    <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body pa-0">
                            <div class="sm-data-box">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center pl-0 pr-0 data-wrap-left" id="tour-day-change">
                                            <span class="txt-dark block counter" id="day-change">@Model.DayChangeString</span>
                                            <span class="weight-500 uppercase-font block">Day Change</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default card-view pa-0">
                    <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body pa-0">
                            <div class="sm-data-box">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center pl-0 pr-0 data-wrap-left" id="tour-12-month">
                                            <span class="txt-dark block counter" id="twelve-month-change">@Model.TwelveMonthChangeString</span>
                                            <span class="weight-500 uppercase-font block">12-Month Change</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default card-view" id="tour-dropdown">
            <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help getting that right panel to stretch to the bottom of the row would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please create a snippet so someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel, not sure how to get the snippet working with the bootstrap, and this is just a piece of the overall page. There is a lot more that is not included. Just hoping there was a simple way to edit the height of a panel dynamically.

My hacky solution is going to be to css the height of that panel but the left 3 rows may change size depending on screensize so the more dynamic I can make it the better.